# Prove that a number $u$ is $\sup S$ given certain properties.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, supremum-and-infimum

### Problem

Let $S$ be a nonempty subset of $\mathbb{R}$, and let $u$ be a number with the
following properties:

1. for each positive integer $n$, the number $u - \frac{1}{n}$ is not an upper bound of $S$, and
2. for each positive integer $n$; the number $u + \frac{1}{n}$ is an upper bound of $S$.

Prove that $u = \sup S$

---

### My Attempt at the Proof:

Let $B$ be $\sup S$ and $u \neq B$, where $B, u\in\mathbb{R}$. Also, let $A=u - \frac{1}{n}$ and $C=u + \frac{1}{n}$ for any $n \in\mathbb{N^+}$.

WLOG, consider when $u>B$. As a result of The Least Upper Bound Principle, for any $x\geq C$, $x$ must be an upper bound of $S$, as $x>B$. However, for any $y 
\le A$, $y$ may be either an upper bound or not. Since $A$ by definition 1 must not be an upper bound in $S$, this is a contradiction. Therefore, $u=B$, such that $u=\sup S$.

---

### Question

Are there any suggested improvements to my proof? Can anyone verify I'm on the right track? I'm new to real analysis and unfortunately do not have answers to validate my proof.

Comment: I think you could write it more clearly and with less words. ie. assume $\sup S\not = u$ and get an immediate contradiction. If the $\sup$ is less than $u$ then there is some $n$ s.t. $u-1/n>\sup S$ and this is not an upper bound so this is a contradiction. If the $\sup$ is more than $u$ then there is some $n$ s.t. $u+1/n<\sup$ and $u+1/n$ is an upper bound. Another contradiction. Done.

Comment: That was the type of proof I was aiming for. Perhaps not clearly stated due to my experience in the topic. Why don't you add an answer? There seems to be more than one way to approach the problem.

Comment: As long as you can prove you can find those $n$ in both cases then the proof is complete. Which simply comes down to proving that $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac 1 n = 0$

Comment: There you go, I tried to write it as clearly as possible for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conditions $a)$, and $b)$ imply that: $\forall n \geq 1, u-\dfrac{1}{n} <\sup(S)\leq u + \dfrac{1}{n}\Rightarrow |u-\sup(S)| \leq \dfrac{1}{n}\Rightarrow |u-\sup(S)| \leq \displaystyle \lim_{n\to \infty} \dfrac{1}{n} = 0 \Rightarrow u = \sup(S)$

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the closest to your intended proof, just explained more clearly.

Assume $\sup S \not = u$

Let $\varepsilon = |\sup S - u| > 0$, then since $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac 1 n = 0 \implies \exists n\in \mathbb N$ s.t. $\frac 1 n < \varepsilon$

Case $1$: $\sup S > u \implies u+\frac 1 n < \sup S$ and $u+\frac 1 n$ is an upper bound on $S$ (by assumption). A contradiction with the fact that $\sup S$ is the *least* upper bound.$\blacksquare$

Case $2$: $\sup S < u \implies u-\frac 1 n > \sup S$ and $u-\frac 1 n$ is not an upper bound on $S$ (by assumption). A contradiction with the fact that $\sup S$ is an upper bound.$\blacksquare$

Answer (score 1):

So are you considering a fixed $n$ or all integers $n$ at once (so $A$, $C$ would be sets...). Anyway, the sentence 'However, ... not.' is not valid for a fixed $n$ and if your are trying to say $y \le sup(A)$ where $A$ would a set of $u - 1/n$ for integer $n$, you still would have to prove that the sup is $n$...

Here is one way to approach it.

Suppose $x < u$. Then by the Archimedian Property of $\mathbb{R}$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n(u-x) >1 $ or $u - \frac{1}n > x$ so all such $x$ cannot be a lower bound. Let $y > u$. Then again by the Archimedian Property, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n(y-u) > 1$ or $y > u+\frac{1}n$ so all such $y$'s are an upper bound. Therefore, it follows that... (what?)

Comment: Hi, apologies, but I had a few typos. A and C should now be used as I intended. Perhaps you can double check my proof to see if it now works?

Comment: Fair point. What if I were to consider A and C as sets so that all n is considered? Or does that complicate things?

Comment: I think it does. I remember seeing this exercise maybe in Rudin or in another book and this is the "standard" solution.