# Proving that $u=\sup S$ using certain conditions.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $S\subseteq \mathbb R$ be nonempty. Prove that a number $u\in \mathbb R$ satisfies $u=\sup S$ if for every $n\in \mathbb N$:

**(i)**: $\Big(u-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)$ is not an upper bound of $S$

**(ii)**:$\Big(u+\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)$ is an upper bound of $S$

**I know that this question has been asked before** [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212407/prove-that-a-number-u-is-sup-s-given-certain-properties) but most of the answers use proof by contradiction whereas I require to proof without contradiction. So please help me regarding my approach.

***My approach***:

By condition **(i)**, we have $\Big(u-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)\in S$, which implies that for some $s\in S$, $\Big(u-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)<s$
Let $\dfrac{1}{n}=\epsilon$

$\therefore$ For all $\epsilon>0$, There exists some $s\in S$ such that $(u-\epsilon)<s$

Now if I can prove that $u$ is an upper bound of $S$, I can imply from previous condition that $u=\sup S$. This is where I am stuck.

Please help me to prove that $u$ is an upper bound from **(ii)**.

Also if you have any alternate approach, please provide that too.

Comment: I think,  $u- \frac{1}{n} \in S$ is wrong.

Comment: @Himadri You are right, but the inference drawn from it that $\exists s\in S: \Big(u-\dfrac{1}{n}\Big)<s$ must be correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $\epsilon >0$  there exist a $n$ such that  $\epsilon >\frac{1}{n}$......(*)

By first condition, for each $\epsilon >0$there exist a $s$ such that $u-\epsilon < u- \frac{1}{n}<s$.

Also ,  from second condition $\sup S \leq u+ \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$. So $\sup S $ is a lower bound for the set $A=\{u+\frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. So, $\sup S \leq \inf A= u$. So $u$ is also an upper bound.

Hence , $u=\sup S$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $s \in S$. For each $n \geq 1$, we know that $s \leq u+\frac{1}{n}$.
Let $n$ tend to infinity, you get : $s \leq u$. QED

Comment: I'm sorry, but is there any other method rather than using this 'n tends to infinity argument?'

Comment: I'm afraid it's either this argument or some hidden proof by contradiction....